# How can I process the ajax request only when needed, not every amount of sec

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Basically, I am developing an ajax chat (php, mysql, javascript, ajax)
there is part of the code where I fetch all chat messages inside a div by using ajax, the ajax function is running every 2 sec.

My main problem is that the div is scrolling down every 2 sec, I need it to scroll down only when there is new entry (scroll down for all chat users not me only)

```
function loadLog(){     
    var oldscrollHeight = $("#chatbox").attr("scrollHeight") - 20;
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajaxchat.php",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            $("#chatbox").html(html); //Insert chat log into the #chatbox div               
            var newscrollHeight = $("#chatbox").attr("scrollHeight") - 20;
            if(newscrollHeight > oldscrollHeight){
                $("#chatbox").animate({ scrollTop: newscrollHeight }, 'normal'); //i need to scroll if only there is new entry not every 2.5 sec 
            }               
        },
    });
}
setInterval (loadLog, 2500);    //Reload file every 2.5 seconds
```

Comment: For that kind of chatting system realtime server/client communication is needed. 
But I think  what you can do here is instead of loading all the messages every 2 sec you can make a request to fetch only recent messages every 2 sec, and push that chat to dom.

Comment: could you give an example ?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to check the new HTML is different to the old HTML before updating the `chatbox`. This will ensure that the `chatbox` is only updated when new content is fetched from the server. However if you response HTML is inconsistent this will not work.

```
var previousChatHTML = '';
function showChatMessages(html) {
    if(previousChatHTML === html){
        return;
    }
    var oldscrollHeight = $("#chatbox").attr("scrollHeight") - 20;
    $("#chatbox").html(html); //Insert chat log into the #chatbox div  
    previousChatHTML = html;   
    var newscrollHeight = $("#chatbox").attr("scrollHeight") - 20;
    if(newscrollHeight > oldscrollHeight){
        $("#chatbox").animate({ scrollTop: newscrollHeight }, 'normal'); //i need to scroll if only there is new entry not every 2.5 sec 
    }               
}

function loadLog(){     
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajaxchat.php",
        cache: false,
        success: showChatMessages,
    });
}
setInterval (loadLog, 2500);    //Reload file every 2.5 seconds
```

Also when creating pollers in JS you may want to use setTimeout (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) instead of setInterval as on slow connections you can get odd results (if a request takes longer than 2.5s it can resolve in the wrong order).

Answer (score -1):

You can't do this with LAMP
You need response to events from server. 
You can do this with this stack

- NodeJS: Javascript on serverside / https://nodejs.org/es/
- Socket.IO: Realtime server/client comunication: https://socket.io/
- Firebase: BaaS Database for realtime comunications https://firebase.google.com/

---

Your server need response to database events.
PHP response to Client events.

Comment: do u have a way where i can scroll the div down only if there is new entry in chat , not always down